# Managin subqueries in sql which have multible rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, twitter

Im doing this small twitter page and I want to query my tweets some how. 
Id like them to have those @(eg. "@someName") signs and when someone follows someone, their tweets will be displayed. 
PHP QUERY:

```
    SELECT * from tweetsTab where username = '".$user."' or username = (SELECT
    followed from followTab where follower = '".$user."') or tweet like CONCAT
    ('%@', (SELECT followed from followTab where follower = '".$user."'), '%') or
    tweet like '%@".$user."%' ORDER BY tweetTime DESC;
```

The subqueries have multible rows which is an error. So im Kinda stuck here and a beginner to SQL.

So how can I query when subquery has multible rows and " IN " doesn't work, so that I can keep sorting by tweetTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

```
SELECT * from tweetsTab where username = '".$user."' or username IN (SELECT
followed from followTab where follower = '".$user."') or tweet like CONCAT
('%@', (SELECT followed from followTab where follower = '".$user."'), '%') or
tweet like '%@".$user."%' ORDER BY tweetTime DESC;
```

Comment: thanks, it works but only when 
     or tweet like CONCAT
     ('%@', (SELECT followed from followTab where follower = 
     '".$user."'), '%') is removed.. Then i cannot have @ control at all.